# Why the chi-square distance gives a better in high dimensional space

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, distance-functions, euclidean

I am a beginner in machine learning. I did a classification program using KNN using two similarity distances: Euclidean distance and chi-square distance.The size of each feature vector is 10000.

I remark that the test using chi-square distance are better than those using Euclidean distance. I have read that Euclidean distance is not a good measure in high dimensional, and as we know chi-square distance is a weighted distance regarding the Euclidean one. So , what is the secret or the intuition that leads chi-square to give a better results?